# OctoberCMS How to Preview

Tags: laravel-5, octobercms

I have a controller that implements `Backend\Behaviors\FormController` and `Backend\Behaviors\ListController`. I'm able to update or delete selected records from the list (delete by clicking the delete button and update by double click), however, I can't find a way to add preview link to the list and I can't find that mentioned in the [documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#configuring-form).

I'm able to preview any records if I enter the preview link manually in the URL bar. e.g.

```
http://my-project.dev/administration-backend/walid/my-plugin/model/preview/1
```

I just want to add the above preview link next to each record in the list.

Comment: So you want a button on each row in the list that when clicked would take you to the preview page for the record?

Comment: Yes I want a link to be clicked to preview each record.

Comment: I think it's possible with list partial, however I wanna be sure if there is something out of the box for this or no?

Comment: You're bang on, you would use a column with `type: partial` that renders a link styled like a button to take you to the correct page. There isn't any behaviour built in for this by default that you could just toggle on unfortunately, but it's not too difficult to do it yourself.

Comment: That's a beauty of OctoberCMS actually . you can do almost anything on this. It will not tie you up. Coming back to the question, as mentioned above in comments, you need to create partial and can call it to achieve this feature. I reckon you are good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments above, the only way to do it is by list partials:

You should define custom list column, quoting [OctoberCMS documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#column-partial):

> #### Partial
>
> `partial` - renders a partial, the path `value` can refer to a `partial`
>   view file otherwise the column name is used as the partial name.
>   Inside the partial these variables are available: `$value` is the
>   default cell value, `$record` is the model used for the cell and `$column`
>   is the configured class object `Backend\Classes\ListColumn`.
>
> ```
> content:
>     type: partial
>     path: ~/plugins/acme/blog/models/comments/_content_column.htm
> ```